# Gallery Image Gridview with Add image Button in Android Studio

Tags: android, gridview

i am working on a design to post some images. i have following design in mind. help me how can i add button in gridview item. to add images to my gridview.

[image]

[following is my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBYWh.png)

Comment: Use a custom layout for the gridview cells with a FrameLayout containing two imageviews(one is original gallery item and other is add button image). Then inside your custom adapter class, provide list count as one more than the original list. So in the last position, enable the add button image instead of the gallery item image.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like this.

GridItem Interface :

```
public interface GridItem {

    public long getId();
    public String getImgUrl();
}
```

ActualGridItem for images:

```
public class ActualGridItem implements GridItem{

private long id;
private String imgUrl;

public ActualGridItem() {
}

public ActualGridItem(long id, String imgUrl) {
    this.id = id;
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getImgUrl() {
    return imgUrl;
}

public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}
```

}

GridAdapter:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private List<GridItem> items;
private Context context;

public GridAdapter(Context context, GridItem addImageItem) {
    this.items = new ArrayList<GridItem>();
    this.context = context;
    this.items.add(addImageItem); // at this moment we only have + item 
}

public void addItem(GridItem actualItem) {
    int insertLocation = this.items.size() - 2; // Before last item, last always will be +
    this.items.add(insertLocation, actualItem);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

@Override
public GridItem getItem(int position) {
    return this.items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return this.items.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = new ImageView(context);
        // Customize image view
    }

    GridItem currentItem = items.get(position);
    // load image with url currentItem.getImgUrl();
    return convertView;
}
```

}

And in Activity or Fragment where your gridview is :

```
GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, new GridItem() {

        @Override
        public String getImgUrl() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "+ image url";
        }

        @Override
        public long getId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return -1;
        }
    });

    gridView.setAdpter(adapter);
```

Later u can simply add new items in adapter with

```
gridView.addItem(actualGridItem);
```

In onItemClickListener check if item id is -1, if so, You clicked on + and do whatever u want do with it.

It's just overall idea of how I would implement it.